# How Jump instruction is executed based on value of Out- The Alu Output

Tags: cpu-architecture

[image: j1, j2 and j3 are bits for the jump instruction and comp instructions are the computation instructions like add etc.]

**Figure from The Elements of Computer System (Nand2Tetris)**

Have a look at the scenario where

```
 j1 = 1 (out < 0 )
 j2 = 0 (out = 0 )
 j3 = 1 (out > 0 )
```

How this scenario is possible as **out < 0** is true as well as **out > 0** but **out = 0** is false. How `out` can have both positive and negative values at the same time?

In other words when `JNE` instruction is going to execute although it theoretically seems possible to me but practically its not?

Answer (score 3):

If out < 0, the jump is executed if j1 = 1.

If out = 0, the jump is executed if j2 = 1.

If out > 0, the jump is executed if j3 = 1.

Hopefully now you can understand the table better. In particular, JNE is executed if out is non-zero, and is skipped if out is zero.

Comment: one more doubt I am having is with ALU control bit inputs. zx control input means that zero the x input and nx means negate(bit by bit) the x input. If both these control bits are 1 then in which order zx and nx operations are done as they produce different result?

Comment: This sounds like a totally different question, and should be asked as such.

Comment: I would like to have a quick solution because I am in middle of something so that's why I am asking in comment. Please do me one more favour.

Comment: Unfortunately, this site doesn't work this way. Perhaps you should ask your TA or helpdesk.

Answer (score 1):

The mnemonic makes sense if those are match-any conditions, not match-all.  i.e. jump if the difference is greater or less than zero, but not if it is zero.

Specifically, `sub x, y` / `jne target` works the usual way: it jumps if `x` and `y` were equal before the subtraction.  (So the subtraction result is zero).  This is what the `if(out!=0) jump` in the Effect column is talking about.

IDK the syntax for Nand2Tetris, but hopefully the idea is clear.

---

BTW, on x86 `JNZ` is a synonym for `JNE`, so you can use whichever one is semantically relevant.  JNE only really makes sense after something that works as a compare, even though most operations set ZF based on whether the result is zero or not.

Comment: one more doubt I am having is with ALU control bit inputs. `zx` control input means that zero the x input and `nx` means negate(bit by bit) the x input. If both these control bits are 1 then in which order `zx` and `nx` operations are done as they produce different result?

Comment: @Rouftantical: I don't know anything about Nand2Tetris.  You'll have to check the docs yourself.  I was only able to answer this because the question included all the necessary info (and jcc instructions are the same on many ISAs.)